# Couchbase n1q1 query to fetch map's specific key

Tags: sql, json, nosql, couchbase, sql++

Below is the couchbase doc
`

```
{
  "docId": "1111212",
  "user": {
    "id": "5050017",  
    "name": "string", 
    "type": "string"
  },
  "books": {
        "1": {
          "id": "1",
          "name": "Book1",
          "author":{
             "id":"A1",
             "name":"name"
          }
        }
      "2": {
          "id": "2",
          "name": "Book2",
          "author":{
             "id":"A2",
             "name":"name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`
I need to fetch all Books  name using select query
I tried this

```
SELECT b.books.*.name FROM bucket_name b   where meta().id like '%books_details%' OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10
```

I am able to get all json keys under books but not the field under each map.

SELECT OBJECT_NAMES(b.books) FROM bucket_name  b where meta().id like '%books_details%' OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM bucket_name AS b 
UNNEST OBJECT_VALUES(b.books) AS u
WHERE .....;

SELECT ARRAY v.name FOR f:v IN b.books END AS names
FROM bucket_name AS b;
```